# Uniformly random subset

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Two people visit their favorite pub that has 10 different beers. They both order, independently of each other, a uniformly random subset of 5 beers.

- One of the beers available is Leo's Early Breakfast IPA. Determine the probability that this is one of the beers that the first person orders.
- Let X be the random variable whose value is the number of beers that are ordered by both of them. Determine the expected value E(X) of X. (Hint: Use indicator random variables.)

---

There are 252 possible subsets of 5 beers that they can order, and if one person orders a specific beer then the probability of this would be 10/252. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Just not quite sure where to start with the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator in your first part is correct: There are $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ ways to choose a subset of 5 beers from 10. However, the numerator of 10 is not quite right; we can anchor one of our choices to be Leo's Early Breakfast IPA, and then we have 4 remaining beers to choose from 9, so the numerator should instead be $\binom{9}{4} = 126$. So, our probability is $\frac{126}{252} = \frac{1}{2}$. Now, we realize there must exist a much more obvious solution to the problem: split the 10 beers into two groups randomly. Then it is utterly obvious that the probability Leo's Early Breakfast IPA is in one pre-specified group is $\frac{1}{2}$!

For the second part, let $I_1, \cdots, I_{10}$ be random variables such that $I_i = 1$ if beer $i$ is chosen by both people, and $0$ otherwise. The probability of $I_i = 1$ is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. We clearly see that $X = \sum_{i=1}^{10}{I_i}$ and so $\mathbb{E}X = \sum_{i=1}^{10}{\mathbb{E}I_i} = \frac{10}{4} = 2.5$. And again, appealing to intuition, the process is equivalent to friend 1 randomly splitting the beers into two groups of five, and then friend 2 doing the same thing. By symmetry, the probability of $k$ overlap is the same as the probability of $5 - k$ overlap, and so we must average out at $\frac{5}{2} = 2.5$.